# Warning: the gem 'chronic' was found in multiple sources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

after running my ruby on rails application i got this error:

```
Warning: the gem 'chronic' was found in multiple sources.
Installed from: http://rubygems.org/
Also found in:
 * http://gemcutter.org/
You should add a source requirement to restrict this gem to your preferred     source.
For example:
gem 'chronic', :source => 'http://rubygems.org/'
Then uninstall the gem 'chronic' (or delete all bundled gems) and then install again.
```

iv'e don this: gem 'chronic', :source => 'http://rubygems.org/' like mentioned ... but then i got this error:

```
-bash: http://rubygems.org/: File or Directory not found
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gem 'chronic', :path => 'http://rubygems.org/'`.

If you want to run it from the terminal, use `gem install chronic -s http://rubygems.org/`.

Comment: i have it twice in my gemfile ... `source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gemcutter.org'` should i delete one?

Comment: @Felix yes you should delete one